# Probability that a bit is $1$ in an infinite binary sequence where $000$ must be followed by $1$

Tags: probability

Probability of "1" and "0" are 1/2 for one position, except three "0" in a row makes next position must is "1", says "0001" is allowed while "0000" is prohibited. So what's probability of "1" in the whole sequence with infinite length?

Probability of "1" is defined as number of "1" divided by number of "1" and "0" in the sequence, what's the limitation when the sequence is infinite?

Comment: But, if I understand correctly, it's **not possible** to have a sequence of length longer than three, that **doesn't have a 1**. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Matti: I assume the OP is asking what is probability of a $1$ in a particular position. Or rather, the limit of this probability as the position tends to infinity. kvtxug, perhaps you should make this clearer.

Comment: @Matti P. you are right.

Comment: Now that the question has been updated, I understand it in a new way: Now it's actually asking: "How many 1's are there, on average?"

Comment: @ Matti P, yes .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can turn this around, and ask "What is the average length of a sequence with $n\, 1$'s?"

Such a sequence can be seen as a sequence of "blocks" of the form $1$, $01$, $001$, and $0001$, with probabilities $\frac12,\frac14,\frac18,\frac18$ respectively. So the expected length of a block is $\frac12\cdot 1+\frac14\cdot 2+\frac18\cdot 3+\frac18\cdot 4=\frac{15}{8}$.

Hence the expected length of a sequence containing $n\,1$'s (ignoring end effects which become negligible as $n\to\infty$) is $\frac{15}{8}n$. So the probability of a $1$ tends to $\frac{8}{15}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you! It works.

Comment: I am getting a (slightly) different answer numerically.  I have posted my method below.  I could certainly have made a conceptual (or a computational) error.

Comment: To  point out a particular issue:  it is simply not true that the probability that that a randomly chosen "good" sequence of fixed length  ends in $1$  is $.5$ as you suggest.  Letting $A_n$ be the number of good sequences, this would be the same as saying that $\frac {A_{n-1}}{A_n}\to .5$ but  the recursion $A_n=A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}+A_{n-3}+A_{n-4}$ has characteristic polynomial $x^4=x^3+x^2+x+1$ which has one root at about $1.9276$ and all the other roots have norm less than $1$.  Thus this limit tends to $\frac 1{1.9276}=.51879$, not $.5$ and this is borne out by the recursion.

Comment: Ah, and we can continue in this spirit to get the "true" probabilities...letting $\alpha =1.9276$ we see that a given good sequence of length $n$ will end with your block of length $i$ with probability $\frac 1{\alpha^i}$ so then your methodology would give the answer $1\Big /\sum_{i=1}^4 \frac i{\alpha^i}= 0.566342887$ which matches the recursion beautifully.

Comment: @lulu, I agree that the probability of the last element being $1$ is not $\frac12$. That's why I said "ignoring end effects which become negligible as $n\to\infty$".

Comment: It's not an "end effect", it is systematic.  Your method greatly over weights the block $0001$.  Consider sequences of length $4$.  Your method gives $0001$ a probability of $\frac 18$ which is twice the probability of any other good sequence.  To be sure, your method may well have been what the OP intended but it is a biased distribution on the collection of good sequences.  I've added some comments to my posted solution discussing the difference between the methods.

Comment: @lulu: Yes, I take your point. I have added my own comment to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine Markov chain with 4 states which model arbitrary position in the string, far from beginning:

- 1: position is $1$;
- 2: position is $0$, previous position is $1$
- 3: position is $0$, previous positions are $10$
- 4: position is $0$, previous positions are $100$

$$\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}   
\enclose{circle}{^2\ 0} & \xrightarrow{\tfrac12} & \enclose{circle}{^3\ 0} & \xrightarrow{\tfrac12} & \enclose{circle}{^4\ 0}\\\
& _{\tfrac12}\searrow\nwarrow^{\tfrac12} & \tfrac12\downarrow & \swarrow\ 1\\\  
 && \enclose{circle}{^1\ 1}\\
&&\circlearrowright\tfrac12\\
\end{array}  
$$

Evidently $p_2=p_1/2$, $p_3=p_2/2$, $p_4=p_3/2$, and
$$p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4=1$$

which gives
$$p_1=\frac{8}{15}$$

Comment: I've coded your Markov chain into MathJax so it can be read more easily. It's not an optimal way of doing it, due to the apparent lack of Markov chain support in MathJax, but if you can find a better way or would like to make a digital image, feel free to improve it.

Comment: @Jam thank you, I fixed one probability.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify a possible ambiguity:  I think there are competing notions of the probability involved here (hence the incompatible results people are reporting).  The way I interpreted the question, I count all the good sequences of length $n$, where a "good" sequence is one that does not contain $0000$.  Call that number $A_n$.  Now count all the $1's$ in all those sequences, calling that number $T_n$. I then compute (or estimate) $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {T_n}{n\times A_n}$.  This may well not be what was intended, but it was how I interpreted the question.

To stress:  generating a good sequence bit by bit, forcing a $1$ after $000$, does not give the same result.  Indeed, I'd argue that this was a biased way of producing good sequences.  Consider, say, sequences of length $4$.  There are $15$ good sequences of length $4$ (as $0000$ is the only bad one) so a uniform measure would give each probability $\frac 1{15}$.  But the bit generator method gives $0001$ probability $\frac 18$, twice the probability of any other good sequence.  As that particular sequence is "poor in $1's$" this method underestimates the probability of getting a $1$ (from the unbiased viewpoint).

As to the unbiased probability:  Recursive methods give us some sense of the answer.

Let $A_n$ be the number of "good" series of length $n$.  Then $A_1=2,A_2=4,A_3=8, A_4=15$ and we have the recursion $$A_n=A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}+A_{n-3}+A_{n-4}$$ since any good sequence of length at least $4$ ends in one of $1,10, 100, 1000$

Now let $T_n$ be the total number of $1's$ in all the good sequences of length $n$.  Then $T_1=1, T_2=4, T_3=12, T_4=32$ and we have the recursion $$T_n=A_n+T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}+T_{n-3}+T_{n-4}$$

This is easily computed and the ratio $\frac {T_n}{n\times A_n}$ appears to approach a limiting value of about $.566$

To compute this analytically, we note that the recursion for $A_n$ has the characteristic polynomial $$x^4=x^3+x^2+x+1$$ which is a "Pisot" polynomial, in that one real root has norm greater than $1$ and all the other roots have norms less than $1$. The associated Pisot number is $\alpha \approx 1.9276$  and it follows that $A_n\sim C\alpha^n$ for some constant $C$.  It follows from this that, for large $n$, we have the ratios $$\frac {A_{n-i}}{A_n}\to \frac 1{\alpha^i}$$.  So the expected length of the "ending block" of a randomly chosen good sequence of length $n$ is $$\sum_{i=1}^4 \frac i{\alpha^i}\approx 1.7657$$

which implies that the desired answer is approximately $$\frac 1{1.7657}=.56634$$ in harmony with the recursion.

Comment: I will confess that I haven't taken the time to try to understand this answer, but I wrote a simulation in R and confirmed the accepted answer of 8/15 (and not this one).

Comment: @AaronMontgomery  What did you compute?  Did you enumerate the good sequences of length $n$ for some large $n$, count all the $1's$ and divide by the total number of slots or did you compute something else?  I expect there may be multiple notions of what the probability means here.  I meant exactly that process...which is hard to simulate.  I would not be surprised to learn that different notions lead to different results.

Comment: I don't know what "good sequences" means here. I simulated the bit generation just as I understood it to have been described -- 100000 binary bits that were random, unless the last three bits were 0 (in which case the bit is just 1). Then, I divided the number of 1s by 100000.

Comment: A good  sequence is one in which the block $0000$ does not occur.  Again, my computation counts all the good sequences of length $A_n$, ($A_n$), counts all the slots in them, $n\times A_n$, counts all the $1's$ in the good sequences, $T_n$, and then computes the limit $\frac {T_n}{n\times A_n}$.  Thus it answers the question "if you take a random slot in a random good sequence of length $n$, what is the probability that it is occupied by a $1$?".  I thought that was what was intended, but it might not have been.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think the original question may imply a non-uniform probability measure on the good sequences -- although maybe my instinct is wrong.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery  Yes, at this point I suspect that the various answers depend on the exact definition of this  measure.  Interesting that the various approaches give different results. Well, it's interesting if no blunder was made...but since I can get my result numerically and analytically I believe that my answer is correct given my definition.  The other notion appears easy to understand and I believe those computations as well.

Comment: I think the OP is fairly clear on this point: the sequence is generated bit by bit, with a $1$ being forced if the previous three elements were $0$. This does indeed give a non-uniform distribution of good sequences.

Comment: @TonyK  Oh, you may well be right about what the OP intends. I still think the unbiased computation is of interest.

Comment: After further reflection, a non-uniform probability distribution is definitely what's happening here. Consider the case of $n = 4$; of the 16 good sequences, under the interpretation I, kludg, and TonyK used, each sequence has probability $1/16$ -- except 0000, which has probability 0, and 0001, which has probability $1/8$.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery  Yes, exactly.  If you look at my posted solution, I added that very example some time back.  And since the biased method favors the $0001$ block, which is low in $1's$, this method underestimates the probability of getting a $1$ (at least from the unbiased point of view).